# FFmpeg - Xstack mutiple inputs for mosaic video output - extra output Blank screen is always green

Tags: ffmpeg, mosaic

I have a website where we combine multple videos with ffmpeg xstack. Its an automated process. When there is not an even number of videos the blank tiles in the mosaic are green. I am trying to figure out how to make the spare blanks Black.

I have tried `xstack=inputs=2:fill='black':layout=0_0` (this gives an error object not found) also tried  `-filter_complex "color=s=1920x1080:c=black"`.

Any suggestions? Here is entire command:

```
ffmpeg -i video1 -i video1 -i video1 -i video1 -i video1 -i video1 -i video1 \ 
    -i video1 -i video1 -filter_complex \
    "color=s=1920x1080:c=black;[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a1];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a2];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a3];[4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a4];[5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a5];[6:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a6];[7:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a7];[8:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a8];[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8]xstack=inputs=9:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0|0_h0|w0_h0|w0+w1_h0|0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1|w0+w1_h0+h1[out] " \
    -map "[out]" output
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the color filter as xstack alone should suffice. 3x3 example with 8 inputs; lower right corner filled with black:

```
ffmpeg -i input -i input -i input -i input -i input -i input -i input -i input -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a1];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a2];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a3];[4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a4];[5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a5];[6:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a6];[7:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a7];[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7]xstack=inputs=8:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0|0_h0|w0_h0|w0+w1_h0|0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1:fill=black[out] " -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

Make sure you're using 4.3+ or a build from the current git master branch.

Comment: Updating ffmpeg and using the fill worked Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you could also use is the `overlay` filter. And overlay the videos over the black background.

```
[background][a0]overlay=x={x}:y={y}[overlay0];
[overlay0][a1]overlay=x={x}:y={y}[overlay1];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to ffmpeg 4.3 or recent git build and add `fill=black` option to xstack.

Comment: Updating ffmpeg and using the fill worked Thank you!